# trusting one certificate by android

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate

I want to use a https connection between android and a website. the certificate of website is verified by geotrust, but still I get `Error in http connection javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Not trusted server certificate`. version of android 2.2.
I have read other similar topics but I could not came out with a solution rather than accepting all certificates which I do not want to apply. can I (in a way) handle this trusting issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds that your droid does not have the geotrust root certificate.

you can manually install it as described in [how-to-install-a-web-certificate-on-an-android-device](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4039/how-to-install-a-web-certificate-on-an-android-device)

Answer (score 0):

the reason for the problem is here:

https://support.servertastic.com/entries/426677-rapidssl-and-geotrust-certificate-not-trusted-on-mobile-device

and the solution is also in the link.

installing root and intermediate certificates solved the problem.